# Function such that $f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: derivatives, power-series

I was trying to solve another problem and come up with the problem if there is a function with closed form such that $$f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!};(n\ge1).$$
I tried to check the condition for compositions of some elementary functions but could not find such function.

Any hints and suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: We can define the function by the series
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k!)}{(2k+1)!}x^k
$$
I don't think this qualifies as a "closed form", though

Comment: According to Mathematica, the function will not be elementary, but involve the errorfunction. If you want me to say more, just tell.

Comment: @mickep could you please show it if it is not very complex expression.

Comment: Yes (even though I'd like not to destroy your calculation-joy). It is $\sqrt{\pi/x}e^{x/4}\textrm{erf}(\sqrt{x}/2)$

Comment: @mickep maybe I do not understand something but this function is not even defined at $0$.

Comment: You can define it as a limit at $x=0$. The error function part is like square root of $x$ (modulo constant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that if we set:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n!}{(2n+1)!}x^n $$
and 
$$g(x)=x\cdot f(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n!}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$$
then
$$ g'(x) = 1+\frac{x}{2}g(x)\tag{1}$$
that is a quite easy ODE to solve. By solving it we get:
$$ g(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\exp\left(\frac{x^2-y^2}{4}\right)\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}\operatorname{Erf}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right),\tag{2} $$
from which:
$$ f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}} e^{\frac{x}{4}}\operatorname{Erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right).\tag{3}$$

Comment: +1, I was about to write down something similar... Very nice.

Comment: The condition on the derivative is valid only for $n\ {\Large\geq}\ 1$. You missed an additional ${\rm f}(0) - 1$ term.

Comment: @FelixMarin: $f(0)-1$ is zero, by the very first line.

Comment: ${\rm f}(0)$ is undetermined ( unknown ) under the conditions given by the OP ( $n \geq 1$ ) unless he/she changes its condition to $n \geq 0$ which I believe it'll occur in any moment. In that case, I won't change my answer because it happens so many times. I like your answer: It's pretty nice. Happy New Year 2015.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> Given $\ds{\fermi^{\rm\pars{n}}\pars{0}={\pars{n!}^{2} \over \pars{2n + 1}!}\,,
> \quad n\ \geq\ 1}$:

\begin{align}\color{#66f}{\large\fermi\pars{x}}&
=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{\fermi^{\rm\pars{n}}\pars{0} \over n!}\,x^{n}
=\fermi\pars{0}
+\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n!}\,{\pars{n!}^{2} \over \pars{2n + 1}!}\,x^{n}
\\[5mm]&=\fermi\pars{0}
+\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n!}\,
{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{2n + 2}}\,x^{n}
=\fermi\pars{0} +\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{x^{n} \over n!}\,
\int_{0}^{1}t^{n}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\fermi\pars{0} + \int_{0}^{1}
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\bracks{xt\pars{1 - t}}^{n} \over n!}\,\dd t
=\fermi\pars{0} + \int_{0}^{1}\braces{\exp\pars{xt\bracks{1 - t}} - 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\fermi\pars{0} - 1
+\int_{0}^{1}\exp\pars{xt\bracks{1 - t}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\fermi\pars{0} - 1
+\root{\pi}x^{-1/2}\expo{x/4}\,{\rm erf}\pars{\root{x} \over 2}}
\end{align}